# Reinstalling windows service. Error101 : Source "ServiceName" already exists on the local computer

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, installation

I am trying to create an install for a windows service package.  I had it install once but now every time I try to uninstall and then re-install it I get the error message above.  I have tried changing the assembly name etc to get it to install without any luck.  I cannot find any reference to the old file servicename.exe file but I stall can't seem to get this to install again.  Can anyone point me towards something that might help me get this uninstalled.  I have trieed the installutil but I need to know where the file is located in order to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this commands in a bat file that runs every time reinstalling. It works fine for me. Try this and see...

```
set path=%path%;%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vXXX

InstallUtil /u YourService.exe

InstallUtil /i YourService.exe

net start "Service name"
```

[EDIT](http://windowstipsandfixes.blogspot.com/2008/05/remove-service.html) :

> If you want to delete/uninstall/remove a Windows service, perhaps left
>   from an incomplete installer, you can use the sc command from an
>   Administrator control prompt: sc delete [servicename].

Comment: `sc delete ServiceName` not work if eventlogsource was first time created on machine not by `instalutil` but from code (by service itself) - gives "already exists" error. On other machines `InstallUtil` works even after `sc delete`ing service, with log source.